# What event to use for a TextBox control to signal text change upon pressing enter?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

TextChanged sends a notification for every key press inside the TextBox control.

Should I be using KeyDown event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The better event to handle here is KeyDown.  KeyDown will fire when the user explicitly types into the box or another components simulates users typing by sending messages to the `TextBox`.  This fits the scenario you described.

If on the other hand you choose to respond to the TextChanged event, you will be responding to every occasion where the text is changed (by user or by code).  This means that your event will be raised if I explicitly say

```
someBox.Text = Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 8):

Yep, in the keydown event:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The KeyPress event works for this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter pressed!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the rest of your Form. When you have an Accept Button, [Enter] in (almost) any control will trigger that button and it would be best to stay away from handling it separate in Textboxes.

Reversely, if you do want to handle it one or more Textboxes, don't use an Accept Button.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar.aspx

Comment: Sorry, glanced at the question and missed the winforms tag.  There is a textchanged event in ASP.NET as well...:-S